# javascript-why only partial code is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code, initially as the page is loading, complete block is executed. But after the page is loaded, only the else condition is getting executed.why?

Please find below complete piece of code.

```js
unction verifyrequestArray(id) {
  console.log("in verifyrequestarray" + requestArray.length);
  var y = true;
  //requestArray=["1012-abc","2089-xyz","1012-abc"];
  var tempArr = [];
  //for removing duplicates in the array
  for (i = 0; i < requestArray.length; i++) {


    if (tempArr.indexOf(requestArray[i]) == -1) {
      tempArr.push(requestArray[i]);
    }
  }
  //alert(tempArr);

  //verify if the value already exists

  for (j = 0; j < tempArr.length; j++) {

    if (tempArr.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      console.log("req id already present in array");
      break;
    } else {

      console.log("req id not present in array");
      return false;
    }
  }

}



function getStatusfromArray(id) {
  console.log("in get status");
  requestStatus = requestArray.hasOwnProperty(id);
  console.log("status for " + id + ":" + requestStatus);
  return requestStatus;
}

function setTooltip(currentTag, status) {
  console.log("in settooltip" + currentTag);
  currentTag.attr("title", status); //setting status a tooltip
}

function getStatusUsingAjax(requestValue, callback) {
  console.log("inside function getStatusUsingAjax");
  var currentStatus;
  GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: link,
    async: false,
    onload: function(response) {

      if ($(response.responseText).find("#P16_STATUS2").size() === 1) {
        currentStatus = $(response.responseText).find("#P16_STATUS2").text();
        console.log("Status is " + currentStatus);
      } else if ($(response.responseText).find("#P16_STATUS3").size() === 1) {
        currentStatus = $(response.responseText).find("#P16_STATUS3").val();
        console.log("Status is " + currentStatus);
      }


      var pusharr2 = [requestValue + "-" + currentStatus];
      requestArray.push(pusharr2);
      //console.log("Updated Array is "+requestArray);

      callback(currentStatus);

    }
  });



}

function loadStatus(x) {

  $('.a-IRR-table tr').each(function(i) {
    var val = $(this).find("td").eq(0).text();
    if ((val !== "-") && (val !== "")) {
      link = $(this).find("td").eq(0).find("a").attr("href");
      linkTag = $(this).find("td").eq(0).find("a");
      console.log("Link Tag is " + linkTag);
      console.log("val is " + val);
      var x = verifyrequestArray(val);
      console.log("x is " + x);
      if (verifyrequestArray(val)) {
        var updatedStatus = getStatusfromArray(val);
        setTooltip(linkTag, updatedStatus);
      } else {
        console.log("in else");
        //var updatedStatus2=getStatusUsingAjax(val);
        getStatusUsingAjax(val, function(updatedStatus2) {
          console.log("UpdatedStatus2 is " + updatedStatus2);
          console.log("Link Tag is " + linkTag);
          setTooltip(linkTag, updatedStatus2);
        });

        sleep(1.5 * 1000);

      }
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: When and how is the loadStatus function called exactly?

Comment: That is probably because your verifyrequestArray function returns false.

Comment: @ Mr Lister, loadStatus  is intended to call as soon as page is loaded.$( window ).load(function() {
  loadStatus();
});

Comment: @ Maantje, Assuming verifyrequestArray returns false, it should atleast execute the console.log() with in verifyrequestArray